# pandasdmx: sdmx.Request leading to SSL Error - bad handshake

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, sdmx

I am using the `pandasdmx` library and would like to access the `IMF` datasource. The following code produces a SSLError.

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandasdmx as sdmx

http_proxy = "my/proxy_server/address"
proxies = {
    "http": http_proxy,
    "https": http_proxy,
}
ssl_cert = Path("path/to/my/ssl_certificate")  # .pem file
data_source = "IMF"

src = sdmx.Request(
    data_source,
    proxies=proxies,
    verify=ssl_cert,
    backend="sqlite",
    fast_save=True,
    expire_after=600,
)

flow_msg = src.dataflow()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-f5bd59ed1595>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/D292498/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_1.py', wdir='C:/Users/D292498/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/D292498/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 24, in <module>
    flow_msg = src.dataflow()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandasdmx\api.py", line 392, in get
    raise e from None
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandasdmx\api.py", line 389, in get
    response = self.session.send(req)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\requests_cache\core.py", line 109, in send
    return send_request_and_cache_response()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\requests_cache\core.py", line 97, in send_request_and_cache_response
    response = super(CachedSession, self).send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sdmxcentral.imf.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/dataflow/IMF/latest (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

However, I can easily load the website/xml document https://sdmxcentral.imf.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/dataflow/IMF/latest in my browser. Also, using the regular `request` library seems to be working properly. The following code produces `status code` 200.

```
from pathlib import Path

import requests

proxy_url = "my/proxy_server/address"
proxies = {"http": proxy_url, "https": proxy_url}
ssl_cert = Path("path/to/my/ssl_certificate")  # .pem file
web_address = "https://sdmxcentral.imf.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/dataflow/IMF/latest"

r = requests.get(web_address, proxies=proxies, verify=ssl_cert)
print(r.status_code)  # 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `sdmx.Request()` is not correctly forwarding the `verify` argument.

As a result, the call to the underlying `request` library will use its standard CA certificate. We therefore need to add our cert information into that particular file.

The following lines of code should do the trick:

```
from pathlib import Path

import certifi

ssl_cert = Path("path/to/my/ssl_certificate")  # .pem file

cafile = certifi.where()

with open(ssl_cert, 'rb') as infile:
    customca = infile.read()

with open(cafile, 'ab') as outfile:
    outfile.write(customca)
```

Please find more details at https://incognitjoe.github.io/adding-certs-to-requests.html.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently, `sdmx.Request()` is not correctly forwarding the `verify` argument.

In `sdmx1`—a more actively maintained fork of `pandaSDMX`—this bug was [noted in an issue on 2020-11-20](https://github.com/khaeru/sdmx/issues/29) and [fixed in v1.6.0 on 2020-12-16](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html#v1-6-0-2020-12-16). `verify` is now honoured, so the manual addition of a certificate in the other answer is no longer necessary.